# Why does this method returning a lambda depend on the return type of the interface method?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am looking at existing code and trying to understand how lambda expressions and functional interfaces work.

Here is the code:

```java
public interface MyComparator<T> {
    public int compare(T t1, T t2);

    public static MyComparator<Person> comparing(Function<Person, Comparable> fun) {
        return (p1, p2) -> fun.apply(p1).compareTo(fun.apply(p2));
    }
}
```

The above piece of code compiles properly without any issues, but if I change the return type of the `compare` method from `int` to `String`, I get an error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String

    public int compare(T t1, T t2);
```

Why is the `comparing` method dependent on the `compare` method?

Comment: Rewrite your title to summarize your specific technical issue. How is your question different from all the other questions on lambda and functional interfaces?

Comment: I'm confused by your code example.  Are you actually trying to redefine the built-in type, [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)?  Why?

Comment: If that's what the OP intends, yes it would be much clearer.

Comment: i was looking at online course for lambda and instructor used Comparator as interface name, so i copied the snippet of code, sorry for confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function type is `Function<Person, Comparable>`, which means `fun.apply(p1)` returns a `Comparable`. This is an interface defined in the Java standard library, which declares a method named [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) which returns an `int`, so therefore your lambda returns an `int`.

This means if you define your functional interface as having a single abstract method returning an `int`, then your lambda conforms to the functional interface because it does return `int`. But if you define that abstract method as returning a `String`, then the lambda does not conform to the functional interface, because it does not return a `String`.

In the latter case, it is a type error for your `comparing` method to return that lambda, since the signature of `comparing` says it should return an instance implementing your functional interface, but the lambda does not conform to that functional interface due to the lambda having the wrong return type.